# At what points is the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{2+e^z}$ holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I need to determine at which points this function is holomorphic. I attempted to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but that got too messy and so I'm trying to find another route. In the first part of the question, I was asked to calculate the first three terms in the Taylor expansion of $f(z)$ around $0$, for which I got $f(z)=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{9}z-\frac{1}{54}z^2+ \cdots$. I've tried to find a way to use this, but I can't think of anything.

Comment: Quotient of holomorphic functions is holomorphic as long as the denominator is non-zero. And when it is zero, it is going to be an isolated singularity according to the difference of the order of that point as a zero of the numerator and denominator.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy So it's holomorphic for $e^z \neq -2$ which would mean it's holomorphic over all of $\mathbb{C}$ except at points of the form $\log 2 + i(2n+1)\pi \, \, \,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is holomorphic wherever $e^z\ne-2$: the quotient of holomorphic functions (defined in the same open set) is holomorphic where the denominator is not zero; it may have removable discontinuities where both the numerator and denominator are zero, but here the numerator has no zeroes,

Since from $e^{x+iy}=-2$ we get $e^x=2$ and $e^{iy}=-1=\cos\pi+i\sin\pi$, we conclude that the function is holomorphic on the whole plane except at points of the form $\log2+i(\pi+2k\pi)$ (for $k$ an integer).

We have
$$
f'(z)=-\frac{e^z}{(2+e^z)^2}=\frac{2}{(2+e^z)^2}-\frac{1}{2+e^z}
$$
and then
$$
f''(z)=-\frac{4e^z}{(2+e^z)^3}+\frac{e^z}{(2+e^z)^2}=
$$
Thus $f(0)=1/3$, $f'(0)=-1/9$, $f''(0)=-1/27$.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\log 2$? Also, shouldn't the $-1/27$ be $-1/54$ as we have $f''(0) = 2a_2$?

And how would I calculate the radius of convergence of the Taylor series as I don't have an expression for a general term of the Taylor expansion?

Comment: @user112495 Yes, it's $\log2$, sorry. The degree two coefficient is $f''(0)/2!=-1/54$.

Comment: @user112495 You can even go on by using the same trick; for instance, $f''(z)=-4(2+e^z)^{-3}+6(2+e^z)^{-2}-2(2+e^z)^{-1}$ and so on.

Comment: Can I use this to find an expression for a general term in the Taylor series? If not, how else can I calculate the radius of convergence of the Taylor series?

Comment: @user112495 The radius of convergence is $|\log2+i\pi|$, which is the singularity nearest to $0$.